# Android : List all process which uses certain resources

Tags: android, process

I am new to android programming.
I want to list all the process which uses/access certain resources like :

- File(s)
- Internet etc

Any sample code or suggestion.

Thanks in Advance ...:)

Comment: Too broad, unclear ...

Comment: I mean to say can I get name of all process which are accessing Internet i.e. Browser,YouTube player etc.

Comment: you should please also edit your question ..

Answer (score 0):

You will get all application name which is using internet,

```
private ArrayList<String> getInstalledAppsWithSpecificPermission(Context context) {

        ArrayList<String> appsPkgName = new ArrayList<String>();

        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        List<PackageInfo> appNamelist = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);
        Iterator<PackageInfo> it = appNamelist.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            PackageInfo pk = (PackageInfo) it.next();
            if ((pk.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) {

                Log.d("System Application which using internet = ", ""+pk.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm));

                continue;
            }
            if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == pm
                    .checkPermission(Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                            pk.packageName))
                results.add("" + pk.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm));
        }

        Log.v("Application using internet = ", appsPkgName.toString());

        return results;
    }
```

Comment: It will give me list of process which are currently using Internet?

Comment: List of all application  which are currently using Internet.